# NSUrlConnection occassionally getting -1003 (DNS issue)

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection

NSUrlConnection occassionally getting -1003 (DNS issue)

But when I go into Safari and everything is fine and can go to any web site.
When I check on the browser, the site I am going to is also returning OK.
Is there some API to call for cleanup? Thanks.

Comment: Which safari you are talking about, i mean did you test that url in your device safari or mac safari ?

Comment: I have this problem too. Haven't found a solution. It's so intermittent that it's very hard to debug. I need to reboot the phone or toggle flight mode to resolve it. Really frustrating.